# Merging of accounts?

Tags: support

So at one point [I had made an account here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/553/brightblades), but over the course of log in attempts, moving around, job, etc. I totally lost track of it.  So I made a new account (this one), and have been happily enjoying the site again.

Is there any way to merge these two accounts? Can the mods tell that these two accounts are associated with the same email address (although I think I had different log in methods, which is why I may have had difficulties)?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something site mods can do directly, you need to [contact support directly](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact). To quote directly from that linked page

> If you need to delete your account, merge accounts, or have an issue that can't be addressed by meta, please use the form below

Comment: How long does it take to resolve usually? I sent the request in the day you answered, and haven't even got a confirmation email.

Comment: @user19555 I have no idea, but to have taken this long without even acknowledging your request sounds to me like something has gone wrong. Maybe ping them another email?

Comment: I JUST got an email!  Now I need to do the recovery tool on the old account. That should be fun.  I'm not even sure I know what email address I used on that.

Comment: AAAAAAGGGGGHHHHH!  The instructions say to edit the accounts.  And the recovery doesn't seem to work because I signed up for both with the same email (as far as I am aware of).  I think the other profile was with an alternate log in method, and I don't know what method that was (brightblades doesn't give me a valid OpenID, which is what I thought it was).  Now what?

Comment: THANK YOU!  Whoever did it, it seems that things are merged.